# Access Function in a Exported Module

Tags: node.js, sql-server, electron

I would like to create a module, where i have a function where i can insert a sql statement and get the result as recordset. Im new to nodeJs and have some trouble in accessing the functions right.

my Modul (sql.js)

```
var exports = module.exports = {};
sql = require('mssql');



let config = {
user: '###',
password '###'
server: '###',
database: '###',
driver: "###",
options: {
    trustedConnection: true
  }
};


var db = function (query) {
var rc;
console.log('verbinde');
sql.connect(config, function (err) {
    console.log('verbinde');
    if (err) console.log(err);

    let request = new sql.request();


    request.query(query, function (err, recordset) {
        if (err) console.log(err);
        console.log(recordset);
        rc = recordset;
    });
})

sql.close();
}

exports.db = db;
```

call

```
const ipc = require('electron').ipcMain;
const sql = require('../../customModules/sql.js');

console.log(sql.db('SELECT * FROM devices'));
```

i get an undefined.
it seems like, the sql.connect isnt rly called.

Comment: `db` doesn't return anything. You wouldn't be able to return a result that could be logged from asynchronous function any way.

Answer (score 0):

You might get better results using a `Promise`. Perhaps something like this (untested):

```
// sql.js

var db = (query) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  console.log('verbinde');
  sql.connect(config, function (err) {
      console.log('verbinde');
      if (err) reject(err);

      let request = new sql.request();

      request.query(query, function (err, recordset) {
          if (err) reject(err);
          console.log('got those records!');
          resolve(recordset);
      });
  })

  sql.close();
})


// call
const ipc = require('electron').ipcMain;
const sql = require('../../customModules/sql.js');

sql.db('SELECT * FROM devices')
.then(data => console.log(data))
.catch(e => console.log(e));
```

Comment: good ida, but still, the sql.connect seems not to ne called :/